# BACKPACK CRUD fields from another table

Tags: laravel-backpack

I got this tricky scenario, I have 2 tables:

- family table 
  [ id, bloc, ap ]
- user table
  [ id, family_id, name ]

> Note : A family has one or more users.

The result should be like this:

When creating the user I need to have 2 fields from the families table in order to hide the families table from the cms user. The family should only be edited from the users profile.

Is there a way to bind this 2 tables into a single form ?

The store method I have written it manually but on the edit form those two fields from families table don't autocomplete.

Comment: Can you add here your tables sutructure, some portion of code, ...

Comment: table family - [ id, bloc, ap ]
table user - [ id, family_id, name ]

In the user edit form i need to edit and autocomplete fields: family.bloc and family.ap .

I have managed to do this by implementing the getBlocAttribute and getApAttribute on the User model.